# Android ToolBar menu items selected state color (Over flow menu items selected color )

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I want to  change **selected state text color** of **overflow menu items** as shown.

[OverFlow menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0RvP.png)

I have tried with styling activity as `<item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/text_color</item>` but this changes the entire color of menu text whether it is selected or not . Is there any way to do this by custom styling ? or i have to do this programmatically ?

I am using Xamarin.Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a menu :

Create a `menu` folder place in `Resource` folder, then create a file.For example, `menu_main.xml` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item
       android:id="@+id/add_item"
       android:title="Add" />
   <item
       android:id="@+id/remove_item"
       android:title="Remove" />
</menu>
```

Then in your `Activity` add the menu in  `OnCreateOptionsMenu` method :

```
public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
{
    MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.ItemId)
    {
        case Resource.Id.add_item:
            Toast.MakeText(this, "You Clicked Add", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            break;
        case Resource.Id.remove_item:
            Toast.MakeText(this, "You Clicked Remove", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlrNA.gif).

#### Update :

You can change the color of the `MenuItem` text by using `SpannableString`, for example :

```
public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.ItemId)
    {
        case Resource.Id.add_item:
            Android.Text.SpannableString s = new Android.Text.SpannableString(item.ToString());
            s.SetSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.Blue), 0, s.Length(), 0);
            item.SetTitle(s);

            break;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already created a menu
`<item android:id="@+id/action_sort_by_duration"
        android:title="@string/sort_by_duration"
        android:showAsAction="never" />'
  <item android:id="@+id/action_sort_by_distance"
        android:title="@string/sort_by_distance"
        android:showAsAction="never" />`
What i need is the color change (blue for selected option and black for unselected ).

Comment: @Shen Worked well.What does Android.Text.SpannableString indicates ?

Comment: @Annu, this is the class for text whose content is immutable but to which markup objects can be attached and detached.